# WebFormView ViewPath capitalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When using the `ViewPath` property, I noticed it comes back with the same capitalization as what was typed in the URL. For instance, if my Views are set up like `Views/Some/Path`, when someone types `/some/path` in the browser, `ViewPath` will return `~/Views/some/path` instead of `~/Views/Some/Path`.

Any ideas how to get that information correctly capitalized? I really just need to know the view that is being rendered, so I'm open to other ideas as long as I can get the proper path to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own Route based off of the `System.Web.Routing.Route` to convert path to be in title case ;like this:

```
public class LowercaseRoute : System.Web.Routing.Route
{
public LowercaseRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) 
    : base(url, routeHandler) { }
public LowercaseRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler) 
    : base(url, defaults, routeHandler) { }
public LowercaseRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, IRouteHandler routeHandler) 
    : base(url, defaults, constraints, routeHandler) { }
public LowercaseRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler) 
    : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler) { }

public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    TextInfo ti = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;

    if (path != null)
        path.VirtualPath = ti.ToTitleCase(path.VirtualPath);

    return path;
}
}
```

idea from [here](http://coderjournal.com/2008/03/force-mvc-route-url-lowercase/).